# Why do I have the left nav vertical line when left nav is disabled?

Tags: bug, status-completed, left-navigation

When I first saw the left nav bar I was horrified, but mostly because of the awful vertical line that appeared with it. When I learned you could disable the left nav I was happy and all was good.

I opened Stack Overflow today and the bar was back. Nuuuuuuuu. Is there any reason it's back, and can we remove it again please?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again ?

Comment: Same here this morning. Utterly annoying....

Comment: @StephenRauch Aha, I didn't see that one! Yes, my post is a cross-site dupe of that one.

Comment: I am having it from 2 days and I hate that line

Comment: and… it's gone.

Comment: That line keeps reappearing. It’s back again on Meta.SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line (as it appeared at the time of writing the question) was unintentional, and [was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314846/338259). The line has reappeared on meta SO but this time [is intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again#comment1033886_314846).